# AWS EC2 Apache Server running, can't ping/ can't reach through web server

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, routes

I have deployed a EC2 Micro Instance on AWS and installed Apache on it, overall rather basic I have to admit to my shame. Once started I am not able to get to the Apache Test Page via the public DNS of the EC2.

I have added (at least I think) the appropriate security group for the inbound traffic.

```
HTTP     TCP    80    0.0.0.0/0
```

I have checked the httpd.conf file and checked if apache is listening on Port 80, which it is

```
[ec2-user@xxx httpd]$ sudo service httpd status
httpd (pid  12079) is running...
```

After trying to reach the webserver through the AWS Public DNS (IPv4), I just receive a TimeOut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not my brightest moment.

While the security group was configured correctly, I accidentally applied the wrong one to the instance ... so effectively I did not forward the traffic to the port accordingly.

Sorry for wasting your time !

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to assign a public IPv4 address. You can follow these steps based on if you need a permanent or temporary one

**Auto-Assigning Public IPv4 Address** (Temporary IPv4 Address)
(instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip)).  This normal type of public IP will be changed upon every EC2 stop or termination, so if you want a permanent public IP, you would need to make an Elastic IP.

**Elastic IPv4** (Permanent IPv4 Address)
(instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-allocating)).  Do keep in mind that Elastic IP's have requirements that need to be met in order to remain free (requirements [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-ip-charges/))

To get your public IPv4 for your EC2 instance afterward, you would:

1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Instances.
3. Select your instance. In the details pane, get the public IP address from the IPv4 Public IP field, and get the external DNS hostname from the Public DNS (IPv4) field.
4. If one or more Elastic IP addresses have been associated with the instance, get the Elastic IP addresses from the Elastic IPs field.

Comment: Thanks @1337gamerman, unfortuneately this did not solve it. I have already a Public IPv4 address associated to the instance (and went through the elastic IPv4 process to make sure it is set right). Still no response from the server.